# rtabmap_ros doesnt display any output

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to  rtabmap_ros. I have installed  rtabmap_ros for indigo & was following steps mentioned in

- http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros

to run the demo_mapping.bag file. The problem is  rtabmap_ros will open but nothing is getting displayed.

Can anyone help me out to solve this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261316/rtabmap_ros-doesnt-display-any-output/) by [shashankbhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/29689/shashankbhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-05-08**:
What exact commands did you use?

**Comment by [shashankbhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/29689/shashankbhat/) on 2017-05-08**:
roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_robot_mapping.launch
rosbag play --clock demo_mapping.bag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cannot reproduce the problem (Indigo binaries, version 0.11.8):

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_robot_mapping.launch
$ rosbag play --clock demo_mapping.bag
```

[image: image description]

If you launch with RVIZ, do you see something?

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_robot_mapping.launch rviz:=true rtabmapviz:=false
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashankbhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/29689/shashankbhat/) on 2017-05-09**:
Even when I run roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_robot_mapping.launch rviz:=true rtabmapviz:=false, I wont get any display

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-05-11**:
Can you copy/paste the terminal output in your question?